# Is there an R function/library where I can switch between different types of kernels for bivariate KDE?

Tags: r, kde-plasma

I am working on a project where I am trying to find the KDE for a bunch of points.  Currently I am using kde.R to find KDE using the standard normal kernel. I want to use different kernels and compare the results. However, while I have found a lot of libraries for univariate data that allows me to pick a certain kernel, this doesn't seem to exist for bivariate data.

Does anyone know if such a function/library exist?

If not, I'm only left with the option of writing my own kernel code!

Comment: Perhaps have a look at [ks](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ks/ks.pdf), it supports multidimensional data.

Comment: Yeah, ks only has the gaussian kernel -doesn't allow other kernels.